# How do I increase the margins on my Wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, css, blogs

Here is the website:

nowgoleft.com

I want to have the menu and the about section aligned to the far left, i'm using the wp editor dashboard. It is set to the left, but there is still alot of white space that I can't seem to fill. How can I solve this?

Comment: nowgoleft.com is too much slow

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this but I can't comment yet. The menu and about sections looks fine to me and are align with the other sections. Would you elaborate your problem further?

Comment: Hi @Noman. There is a reason why I wrote "Sorry for this but I can't comment yet". I'm sure you know this but we people with low reputation at the moment can't comment yet until we reach 50.

Comment: You can see that there's still alot of white space to the left and right of the about section. I want to bring it to the farthest of the white area.

Comment: A quick fix would be finding the "container" containing the about content(text and image). setting it to width: 100%, then .wpb_wrapper: 
text-align: justify; .wpb_single_image .vc_figure: float: right; remove margin-bottom: 35px from .wpb_content_element, ul.wpb_thumbnails-fluid > li, .wpb_button. I'm just eyeballing it in Inspect Element so please bare with me.

Comment: But IMHO the white spaces are the least of your problems. Your page loads at least 10secs and that's bad for a blog site.

Comment: yeah the loading problem is because of unformatted images.